# How to fix "Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'UUID'" in Django

Tags: mysql, django, database, error-handling, migration

I'm creating an app for my web-app, and Django raises the error shown below when I try to migrate my model to the MySQL database.

All migrations were working perfectly before. I discovered that CarInstance id was tied to the primary key (pk) which was incompatible with the simple url schema I was going for int:pk/> which would be (showroom/car/2).

I tried to moving the 'id' variable to another class with a simple copy/paste which would link to CarInstance as a foreign key similar to what MDN does with their book & BookInstance models here. I thought this would help create a separate primary key, but here I am. :-)

**urls.py**

```
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('cars/', views.CarListView.as_view(), name="cars"),
    path('car/<slug:uuid>/', views.CarDetailView.as_view(), name="car-detail"),
],
```

**Models.py code (with the other code omitted):**

```
class CarInstance(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey('Manufacturer', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    car_model = models.CharField('Model', max_length=50, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=4000)
    vin = models.CharField('VIN', max_length=17, help_text='Enter the 17 character VIN number.', blank=True, null=True)
    mileage = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Mileage')
    car_images = models.ImageField(help_text='Upload pictures', upload_to=image_directory_path, storage=image_storage)
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    engine_displacement = models.CharField(default=2.0, max_length=3, help_text="Engine displacement in Liters (E.g. 2.0, 4.2, 6.3)")
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4,
    help_text="Unique ID for this car.", editable=False)
```

**Exception Error**

I expected the migration to go as normal, but it throws this error instead. I'm not sure where the break-point is, so I just posted the entire block here.

```
C:\code\torque>py manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, showroom
Running migrations:
  Applying showroom.0012_auto_20190930_0701...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 71, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 209, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 315, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 226, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1292, "Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: '6ec1fa4ccc0b44f5b51269ff3c831929                                                                '")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 234, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 249, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 535, in alter_field
    old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 685, in _alter_field
    params,
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 137, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 71, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 209, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 315, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 226, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1292, "Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: '6ec1fa4ccc0b44f5b51269ff3c831929                                                                '")
```

Notice there's a huge gap between the end of the id (29) and the closing quotation marks

**Update:**

I've been working on this for the past few hours, and I still can't make the migration. I've discovered that the urls to specific CarInstances use the UUID, (e.g. showroom/cars/6ec1fa4c-cc0b-44f5-b512-69ff3c831929) which are unsightly. And, even though the syntax is correct, and they're linking to the correct id, the pages still don't work. They're throwing a **404** page not found error.

I'm trying to incorporate slug methods into the url, but I can't make any changes to the model because of the original problem.

If there's any additional info you need, just let me know.

Comment: I don't really understand why you want a UUID but you don't want it in the URL, but never mind. At this point I think your migrations have got out of sync; I think you should delete them all and drop your database, then start again.

Comment: 1. For better looking urls (showroom/cars/2/ is much cleaner than car/6ec1fa4c-cc0b-44f5-b512-69ff3c831929/) 2. I read that using the uuid in urls exposes the data to security leaks. It's just about setting it up the right way. Do you mean delete the entire database, or just the objects themselves?

Comment: 1) yes so why do you want a uuid at all? And 2) no it's the **other way round**. Sequential IDs in URLs are a potential security leak, uuids are *not*.

Comment: Deleting the table worked perfectly! I've answered it below. And as for why, both tutorials I used included UUIDs with the pk remaining just fine, so I just accepted it as mandatory. Anyway, I'll continue to use them for the security. Thanks Daniel!

Answer (score 0):

Since this issue is rare for the Django/Mariadb combination, here are the steps I took to clear the issue. For future readers.

1. Opened the MySQL Client command.
2. Entered my password, then changed my database

`MariaDB [(none)]> use torquedb`

3. Deleted the database, and created a new one.

```
MariaDB [torquedb]> DROP database torquedb;
Query OK, 12 rows affected (0.089 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE database torquedb
    -> ;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> show tables
    -> ;
ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected
MariaDB [(none)]> use torquedb
Database changed
```

4. Then I reran the migrations

```
(torque) C:\code\torque> py manage.py makemigrations
torque) C:\code\torque> py manage.py migrate
```

Luckily, the site is under construction and I only had three objects for testing. :-)